# Build iOS project got duplicate symbols for architecture i386 error

Tags: ios, c, xcode, mqtt

I'm using paho MQTT library in my project.

[image]

And when I build the project on simulator , I got the following errors.

`duplicate symbol _client_version_eye in:
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTClient.o
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTAsync.o
duplicate symbol _Log_levels in:
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTPacket.o
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTAsync.o
duplicate symbol _Log_levels in:
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTPacket.o
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTProtocolClient.o
duplicate symbol _Log_levels in:
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTPacket.o
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/Socket.o
duplicate symbol _Log_levels in:
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTPacket.o
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTPersistence.o
duplicate symbol _Log_levels in:
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTPacket.o
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/Thread.o
duplicate symbol _Log_levels in:
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTPacket.o
    /Users/xieweizhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mgiosapp-bctgnqpjhalyqageaduowfwrsrkh/Build/Intermediates/mgiosapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mgiosapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MQTTProtocolOut.o
ld: 25 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: I've solved this problem. There is an enum duplicate define , and I extern it. Then remove MQTTClient file like @ralight said.

Comment: if my answer helps you please upvote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQTTClient.c and MQTTAsync.c should not be included in the same project. They are used to build different libraries. Decide whether you want the blocking or async behaviour and use that file.

Comment: No, MQTTClient and MQTTAsync can be used in the same project . Here is an example  [MQTT-Client-Frame](https://github.com/ckrey/MQTT-Client-Framework) .

Comment: MQTT-Client-Framework is a native Objective C implementation of an MQTT client. It is completely unrelated to the Paho C clients. MQTTClient.c and MQTTAsync.c implement the same functions. You can't include them in the same executable.

Comment: I try to delete MQTTClient.c and MQTTClient.h files , and still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try it....

The error may occur when you copy and paste the contents of one file to another file with its interface name which means two classes with same interface name.

In your code you have two different files with the same Interface name.

The problem is most likely due to a typo when including the header.

Check so that the header file (.h) is included and not the implementation file (.m).

Also Clean your project and build folder sometimes it will also solve this error

Also delete the derived data.

Comment: @Dee you have added all the files from another project see all file in finder also or not. i any one is double. check it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get this error even if I didn't import any files of this library.

Comment: @Dee remove all the files which you have added in your project and clean and run. if it works then again add the file and check it will works perfectly.

Comment: I just drag and drop the library source code into my project . Do I miss some settings in Xcode?

Comment: @dee yes. you need to add file. like first click on file- add files-then select file which you want to add, check the copy at destination option and click on done.

Comment: I did select destination option correctly. And I can import the library .

Comment: @Dee then try to run it. and inform me if there is any problem.

Comment: It didn't work , I have delete it and copy it into project several times though.
And I've tried to make a static library too, but I got the same error message.

Comment: @Dee check have to imported any .m file in any viewController. check it i think you are doing something in wrong manner.

Comment: > have to imported .m file in any viewController.

NO, I only import the header file.

And, without import any files of the library , I got the same error.

Comment: @Dee go to window and click on project .select your project and click on delete.. (it will delete derived data.) try it clean the build and run.